# Фиксированный горизонтальный скрол-бар в HTML таблице. (CSS, jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, table

Как сделать фиксированный горизонтальный скрол-бар в HTML таблице. То есть необходимо чтоб скрол-бар всегда оставался видимым

https://jsfiddle.net/ghostcom/mxz4b6w7/11/

```
введите сюда код
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что Вам надо. Добавьте `max-height` для `.box`

Comment: `.box { overflow-x: scroll; max-height: 200px; }`

Comment: Спасибо, такой вариант не подойдет. Нужен плавающий скролбар, и не ограничивать таблицу по высоте. Уже понял что задача непростая, даже готовых скриптов не нашел. Пытаюсь сам накидать на JS. Делаю самодельный драгабл скролбар, пока выходит не фонтан)